# Getting the correct Joins

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to get all the Accounts that are ENROLLED.

I have 4 tables.

The tAuditTracking has  all of the users info as follow:

```
ID    Contract_ID        IP Address          LoginID      Activity    Step
1       376877          192.111.4.100        sam@gmail      1         Login
2       376878          192.111.4.100        Bob@gmail      2         Enroll
3       376879          192.111.4.100        Tom@gmail      3         LogOut


ActivityStatus
   1
   1
   2
```

The Second is tlkCustPortalStatus

```
StatusID   Portal Status
1              Pass
2              Fail
```

The Third table is tlkCustPortalActivities

```
ActivityID         Portal Activity
1                       Login
2                       Enroll
3                       Logout
```

The last table is tcontract

```
Contract_ID       Account Number
376877                34104253
376878                35104252
376879                31104257
```

This is my code. I know its horrible but I am helping my superior. So please any tips or help would be appreciated

```
ALTER PROC spCustPortalEnrolledAccounts


(@ENROLLED INT)


As
 Begin

SELECT A.ID, A.CONTRACT_ID, 'A.IP ADDRESS',A.DATE,A.LOGINID,A.ACTIVITY,A.STEP,A.ACTIVITYSTS,A.ADDITIONALDATA,B.ENROLL
FROM tAuditTracking A

JOIN tlkCustPortalActivities B ON B.ActivityID = A.Contract_id
WHERE B.ActivityID = 2

END
GO

EXEC spCustPortalEnrolledAccounts'2'
```

Comment: Why this parameter (@ENROLLED INT), when you are not using it in your query ? You can use it in your query like Where B.ActivityID = @ENROLLED instead of B.ActivityID = 2

Comment: Im thinking I shouldn't even need a parameter if I am just creating a report for all enrolled account on one report.

Comment: Looks like the same question you asked here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1609686-391-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues. ram_sql pointed out you're using a parameter and even EXECing the procedure with a value, but in the actual Stored Procedure this value is hard coded as

```
WHERE B.ActivityID = 2
```

Change that to

```
WHERE B.ActivityID = @ENROLLED
```

Secondly, and more importantly, I can only guess running the procedure either nets NO Rows or very few? The join in the following makes little sense based on the values you've got in the tables.

```
FROM tAuditTracking A
JOIN tlkCustPortalActivities B ON B.ActivityID = A.Contract_id
```

Your A.Contract_ID values are 6 digit numeric values but your B.ActivityID values are single digit numerics.

While what follows is unlikely to be what you want, and I'm basing that on the fact you're attempting to join on CONTRACT_ID which appears to have a relationship to table tcontract, however there is insufficient information to go from tAuditTrackng through tcontract joining on ContractID through to tlkCustPortalActivities. However, it does appear to satisfy your needs to get all Accounts from tAuditTracking with the supplied parameter value (in this case, 2 for ENROLLED)

```
SELECT A.ID, A.CONTRACT_ID, 'A.IPADDRESS',A.DATE,A.LOGINID,A.ACTIVITY,
A.STEP,A.ACTIVITYSTS,A.ADDITIONALDATA,B.ENROLL
FROM tAuditTracking A
JOIN tlkCustPortalActivities B ON B.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
WHERE B.ActivityID = @ENROLLED
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I understand what you mean now, and also I learned a lot from the code. Thank you very much for explaining and not being a snob like most people on here